# unable to update timstamp evertime I update query in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update timestamp everytime I update the row in sqlite.I tried the code below and crashes at :

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "05": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE databasetable3 SET Stats = 1 ,timestamp = 2015/01/07 05:27:56  WHERE No = 2
```

:

```
String CREATE_TABLE3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + databasetable3 + "("+ KEY_sno + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  " + KEY_Stats+ " VARCHAR,  " + KEY_No+ " VARCHAR , " + "timestamp"+ " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE3);



DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
ourdatabase.execSQL("UPDATE databasetable3 SET Stats = "+Stats+" ,timestamp = "+dateFormat.format(date)+"  WHERE No = "+no);
```

Comment: use `ourdatabase.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make type of timestamp a string or don't pass it as a date object instead use milliseconds.

Comment: if I make it string/text will greater than timestamp in query work ?

Comment: nope. Use long instead as I said in my answer. Milliseconds would be in long. there you can use greater/lower than.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use triggers.
Check [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm), I'm sure it is much better than doing this by code !

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I use trigger with the above query.Basically how would the modified query look ?

Comment: check the example in the tutorial I posted, it's pretty much what you should try !